# NASM in Windows, Hello World examples comparison

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

These two examples, do the same thing, they just print a `"Hello, World!"` message:

**Example 1:**

```
global  _main
extern  _printf

section .text
   _main:
       push message
       call _printf
       add esp, 4

       ret

   message:
       db "Hello, World!", 13, 10, 0
```

and this is the command line:

`nasm    -fwin32    0.asm
 gcc      0.obj`

**Example2:**

```
global _main
extern _ExitProcess@4, _printf

section .text
    _main:
        push message
        call _printf
        add esp, 4

        push 0
        call _ExitProcess@4

    message:
        db "Hello, World!", 13, 10, 0
```

and this is the command line:

`nasm    -fwin32    0.asm
 gcc      0.obj`

My question is, when to use an `_ExitProcess@4` function? and when to use just a `ret`?

Comment: @Harry Johnston thank's

Answer (score 1):

Returning from `main()` usually results in `exit()` which in turn calls `ExitProcess()`; but if you're writing in assembly you normally end up taking the raw entry point rather than `main()`, from which returning calls `ExitThread()`.

More information on the raw entry point: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573/

Comment: actually I didn't understand the second part of your sentence.